# Error when running app through android phone via eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, lg, optimus

For some reason, when running the app (Android 2.3.3) for testing on my phone (LG Optimus S, running Android 2.3.3) instead of an emulator (using eclipse), I get this error:

```
[2012-06-12 15:54:59 - test] Failed to install test.apk on device 'A0000028CD875E!
[2012-06-12 15:54:59 - test] closed
[2012-06-12 15:54:59 - test] Failed to install test.apk on device 'A0000028CD875E': closed
[2012-06-12 15:54:59 - test] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: closed
[2012-06-12 15:54:59 - test] Launch canceled!
```

I have enabled usb debugging on my phone. Is there anything else I should be enabling to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you also allow the installation of non-Market applications on your device.  The apk generated by eclipse during debugging is not signed the same as published applications.  Also make sure your computer has all the necessary drivers for your phone.

Comment: I have enabled the installation of non-Market applications, and I'm sure I have the necessary drivers for my phone, seeing that I am able to detect it via "adb devices" command on linux. Is there anything else I should look for?

Comment: Well if your on linux, you shouldn't have to jump through any hoops to get your adb devices working.. Ive never seen that error before. you could try checking to make sure the app isn't already on the device, although I'm sure you checked that already.  Try listing the devices using "adb devices" in your terminal. Also, I am sure you have done this already, but make sure your manifest is set up for the right version and correct sdk's are downloaded.

Comment: I feel it should be the right version. I am able to load the apk onto my phone, and install it from there,  but not able to load the app via eclipse for testing.